# Unknown column 'e.eid' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL and getting this error, here are below code snippets from my works_on table & the inserts

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `works_on`;
CREATE TABLE works_on(
eid INT NOT NULL,
pid INT NOT NULL,
start_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (eid, pid),
FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES employee(id),
FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES project(id)
);

INSERT INTO works_on
(eid, pid, start_date)
SELECT
e.eid AS eid, p.pid AS eid, '2012-01-01'
FROM project p, employee e
WHERE e.first_name = 'Adam' AND e.last_name = 'Lowd'
AND p.name = 'Diamond';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you intend:

```
INSERT INTO works_on (eid, pid, start_date)
    SELECT e.id AS eid, p.id AS pid, '2012-01-01'
    FROM project p CROSS JOIN
         employee e
    WHERE e.first_name = 'Adam' AND e.last_name = 'Lowd' AND p.name = 'Diamond';
```